# Plotting a heat map onto background in python using kde?

Tags: geopandas, contour, heat-map, kernel-density

I have a geodataframe with points within the united states. Each point has a geometry attribute as well as a value. I would like to plot a heat map based on these values on top the map of the united states using kdeplot. However, I'm not sure how `gplt.kdeplot` reads these data frames?

```
contiguous_usa = gpd.read_file(gplt.datasets.get_path('contiguous_usa'))
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.Lat, df.Long)]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df["Gain1"], crs=crs, geometry=geometry)

ax = geoplot.kdeplot(
    gdf, clip=contiguous_usa.geometry,
    shade=True, cmap='Reds',
    projection=geoplot.crs.AlbersEqualArea())
geoplot.polyplot(contiguous_usa, ax=ax, zorder=1)
```

First five rows of my geodataframe looks something like this, column "Gain1" are the values I want to use for the heatmap. 
[image]

Comment: Not sure what the gplt.kdeplot takes as the value column for each point

Answer (score 7):

gplt.kdeplot do not uses the value column for each point, but you can select the column row values of the GeoDataFrame for that as in [KDEPlot of two NYC traffic accident contributing factors](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/gallery/plot_nyc_collision_factors.html) (qualitative values)

For quantitative values, I use one of my shapefiles

1)  With all the values of a column (quantitative values DIP from 0 to 90)

```
gplt.pointplot(df, projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea(), hue='DIP', legend=True)
```

[image]

```
gplt.kdeplot(df,projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea(), cmap='Reds', shade=True, shade_lowest=True)
```

[image]

```
ax = gplt.kdeplot(df,projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea(), cmap='Reds')
gplt.pointplot(df, hue='DIP', legend=True, ax=ax)
```

[image]

2) analyze only DIP values > 75

```
ax= gplt.pointplot(df[df['DIP'] > 75], projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea(), hue='DIP', legend=True)
gplt.kdeplot(df[df['DIP'] > 75],cmap = 'Reds',ax=ax)
```

[image]

or only DIP values = 75

```
 gplt.kdeplot(df[df['DIP'] == 75],cmap = 'Reds',projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea(),shade=True, shade_lowest=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I looked at the nyc collisions data frame, could you please clarify what DIP is?

Comment: I thought it would be a column of quantitative values in the nyc collisions data frame but it seems like it isn't?

Comment: I use here my data for example and DIP is a quantitative data

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm too late, but did I understand correctly saying that KDE is not taking into account the values of the records, but their density? Using your dataset as example, If I have 1 observation very far any other observation with a DIP value of 90, and 1000 observations with low DIP = 1 close to each others, I would end up (with `cmap = 'Reds'`) with a high density (dark red) for the latter and light red (low density) for the former with greater DPI?